# ionic 3 _ Virtual Scroll only displays 1 item on scrolling

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I’m having a matter with ionic virtual scroll and really in need for any possible suggestions to solve it. In short, I have an array that I will fetch data from an API to it. For now, the API’s returning around >100 records (with no offer of pagination) and this number is expected to grow more so Virtual Scroll seems like a good fit. However, there’s a weird problem with how the scroll functions. At first, it displays a few records to fill up the height of the display, then when you start the scrolling, there will be only one item left which will then be replaced by the next item on the list. I’ve attached a small video so you guys could have a better insight into this matter (https://streamable.com/b79xv 1)

Much appreciation.

Here is the related piece of code:

```
<ion-list [virtualScroll]="listOfUnassignedCases" approxItemHeight='50px'>
    <ion-item *virtualItem="let case" (click)="goToAssignConfirm(case)">
      <img style="width:15%;height:auto; margin-right:15px" item-start [src]="case.imageurl" (error)="global.updateImgUrl($event)"/>
      <p style="color:#7e3d92;">{{case.dia_diem_diachi}}, {{case.dia_diem_phuong}}, {{case.dia_diem_quan}}</p>
      <p>{{case.noi_dung}}</p>
      <p>{{case.ngay_phat_sinh}}</p>
      <p style="color:#c14f4f;">Người báo: {{case.nguoi_bao_sdt}}</p>
      <p>{{case.trangthai}}</p>
      <ion-icon item-end ios="ios-arrow-forward" md="ios-arrow-forward"></ion-icon>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

Comment: please check your element's height.

Comment: Thank @KelvinKCS , pls check my post, I've updated the piece of code I'm currently using. The height of child element is set to 50px but I'm not quite certain of how to determine this number since every screen size is quite different.